# Linux Device Tree: Understanding how a reference to a deleted node works?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

## Context

I've taken a look at the device tree that is in use for a working i.MX6 based development board. I've noticed that in the case of the ethernet configuration, a confusing mix of directives are present. Namely:

1. Node `fec1` contains a directive to *delete* node `mdio`
2. Node `fec2` contains a reference to node `ethphy1`
3. Node `ethphy1` is **within** `mdio`, the deleted node.

---

#### Snippet

```
&fec1 {
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet1>, <&pinctrl_enet1_gpio>;
        /delete-node/ mdio;
};

&fec2 {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet2>, <&pinctrl_enet2_gpio>, <&pinctrl_enet2_mdio>;
        phy-mode = "rmii";

        /* Reference */
        phy-handle = <&ethphy1>;
        phy-reset-gpios=<&gpio5 5 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        phy-reset-duration=<100>;
        status = "okay";

        /* Deleted node */
        mdio {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                /* Referenced node */
                ethphy1: ethernet-phy@3 {
                        compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
                        micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
                        micrel,led-mode = <0>;
                        clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
                        clock-names = "rmii-ref";
                        reg = <3>;
                };
        };
};
```

#### Question

What is the final effect of deleting a node in which a child node is referenced? Is the reference broken. Is only the parent node deleted?

Comment: Inspect the actual installed Device Tree of the running system at **/proc/device-tree/** instead of only looking at source code.

Comment: Which source file is this snippet from?

Comment: Since `&fec1` is a reference to some previously defined node, I guess that node contained a node called `mdio` that is being deleted here, which is nothing to do with the `mdio` node contained in the node referenced by `&fec2`.

Comment: @IanAbbott This is the DTS: https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR version

The `/delete-node/ mdio;` directive is deleting the `mdio` node that was added in [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi) or [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi).

## Full version

OP pointed to [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi) as the source of the fragment. That is included by the following:

- [imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi)
- [imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi)
- [imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi)

One of those is included by at least the following, according to their `imx6ul`, `imx6ull`, or `imx6ulz` prefix:

`ims6ul`:

- [imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts)
- [imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts)

`imx6ull:`

- [imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts)
- [imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts)

`imx6ulz`:

- [imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-emmc-wifi.dts)
- [imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-nand-sd-card.dts)
- [imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som-concerto-board-nand-wifi.dts)

Those all include one of the following, according to their `imx6ul`, `imx6ull`, or `imx6ulz` prefix:

`imx6ul`:

- [imx6ul-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-var-som.dtsi), which includes [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi)

`imx6ull`:

- [imx6ull-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-var-som.dtsi), which includes [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi)

`imx6ulz`:

- [imx6ulz-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ulz-var-som.dtsi), which includes [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi)

[imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som.dtsi) and [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart.dtsi) both contain this section:

```
&fec1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet1>, <&pinctrl_enet1_gpio>, <&pinctrl_enet1_mdio>;
    phy-mode = "rmii";
    phy-reset-gpios=<&gpio5 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    phy-reset-duration=<100>;
    phy-handle = <&ethphy0>;
    status = "okay";

    mdio {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        ethphy0: ethernet-phy@1 {
            compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
            micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
            micrel,led-mode = <1>;
            clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
            clock-names = "rmii-ref";
            reg = <1>;
        };
    };
};
```

That modifies the node referenced by `&fec1` (which is defined in [imx6ul.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul.dtsi)) and adds a sub-node called `mdio`. But the [imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/5.4-2.1.x-imx_var01/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-imx6ull-var-som-concerto-board.dtsi) referred to by OP contains this section:

```
&fec1 {
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet1>, <&pinctrl_enet1_gpio>;
    /delete-node/ mdio;
};
```

That also modifies the node referenced `&fec1`. The `/delete-node/ mdio;` directive removes the `mdio` sub-node added earlier.

## Effect of `/delete-node/` in the device tree compiler

Deleting a node with `/delete-node/` removes the node, any label attached to the node, any properties contained in the node, and recursively, any nodes contained within the node. If the node being deleted by `/delete-node/` does not exist, then the directive is silently ignored.

If a node is deleted, any references to the node (or referenced to any label that was attached to the node) from elsewhere in the device tree source will no longer be valid, so the device tree compiler will produce an error *"Reference to non-existent node or label"* when compiling the source.

## Effect of `/delete-node/` in device tree overlays

The `/delete-node/` directive only affects the source being compiled. If it is used in the source for a device tree overlay, the `/delete-node/` directive will have no effect on the live device tree to which the overlay is applied. There is nothing in the compiled dtbo output to say that a node should be deleted from the live tree when the overlay is applied.

## What about `/delete-property/`?

The `/delete-property/` directive is similar to `/delete-node/` except that it is for deleting a property and any label attached to the property.

Comment: I would have liked if you could explain *what* the effect of deleting a node (to which a child is referenced) does to the tree (which was more my angle). But you wrote a good explanation of the include directives.

Comment: @Micrified I've added some sections to the end of the answer about the effect of deleting a node (or a property).